# Examine for conditional and absolute convergence: $\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos y\,\mathrm{d}y}{(y+\sin y)^\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

I need to examine the integral $$\int\limits_1^\infty \frac{\cos y \,\mathrm{d}y}{(y+\sin y)^\alpha}$$ for conditional and absolute convergence based on $\alpha$'s values.
Since this integral looks like none of the templates we use, I tried going the following way:
$$\int\limits_1^\infty\left|\frac{\cos y\,\mathrm{d}y}{(y+\sin y)^\alpha}\right|\le\int\limits_1^\infty \cfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{(y+\sin y)^\alpha}$$ but then I don't know what to do. The only way of going forward that I can think of is substitution but I don't think it will be of any use.
Note that the problem was originally with $\frac{1}{x}$ instead of $y$ but I thought it would be a good idea to simplify it.
Could someone give me at least a hint, please?

Comment: Your MathJax code was full of purposeless complications. If you really need to use software to write the code for you, it appears that there are now packages that will write such code without making it look like something done by a lunatic.

Comment: $$\dfrac1{(y+1)^\alpha} \le \dfrac1{(y+\sin y)^\alpha} \le \dfrac1{(y-1)^\alpha}$$ for $y > 1, \alpha > 0$.

Comment: The original problem was $$\int_0^1 \dfrac {\cos \frac 1x}{x^2\left(\frac 1x + \sin \frac 1x\right)^\alpha} dx\; ?$$

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, exactly.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for the idea. It's helpful. Now, $\frac{1}{(y+1)^\alpha}\sim\frac{1}{(y)^\alpha}$ when $x\rightarrow\infty$, is that right?

Comment: Well, let's see. The ratio of the two functions is $$\dfrac{y^{-\alpha}}{(y+1)^{-\alpha}} = \left(\dfrac{y+1}{y}\right)^\alpha= \left(1 + \frac 1y\right)^\alpha$$ Since $1+\frac 1y \to 1$ as $y \to \infty$ and raising to a constant power is continuous, we're good.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you very much. You're pretty much the only person investing time into my question. Even my lecturer hasn't yet bothered explaining how these integrals (with whole expressions to the power of a parameter) work. Thanks again.